# SQL (Access): Limiting Results with two Dependents

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010, conditional-statements

I am fairly new to SQL and Access, so what I am trying to do might be very simple or maybe not possible the way I intent to do it.

I have made a query which lists all products sold (incl. value and volume) by region and date (month and year). If a product has been sold I would like the query to return all 12 months of the year for that particular product and region. This all works. However, I would like to limit my query by excluding all entries where the sale of a product is "0" in a year for any particular product and region.

Example: If a product has not been sold in a particular region, within a specific year, the query should not return any entries for the product and region in that year. Is this possible?

In below code NationalCode = product, and RegionCode = Region. Everything else should be self-explanatory I hope. :)

I think the solution requires a WHERE statement, I have included a clause which only return values above "0". But this also removes any month which is 0, if there has been sales in a given year I would like to retain months with no sales.

I hope above makes sense. Thank you!

```
 SELECT IIf(isnull(sum(MonthlyData.[Sales
 Value])),0,(sum(MonthlyData.[Sales Value])/1000)) AS [Value],
 IIf(isnull(sum(MonthlyData.[Sales Units])),0,sum(MonthlyData.[Sales
 Units])) AS Volume, [02-Query-Filter].RegionCode,
 [02-Query-Filter].NationalCode, [02-Query-Filter].Year, [02-Query-Filter].RawMonth 

 FROM [02-Query-Filter] 

 LEFT JOIN MonthlyData 

 ON ([02-Query-Filter].RegionCode=Left(MonthlyData.Region,2)) AND
 ([02-Query-Filter].NationalCode=MonthlyData.[Nordic Code]) AND
 ([02-Query-Filter].RawMonth=MonthlyData.Month) 

 WHERE MonthlyData.[Sales Value]>0

 GROUP BY [02-Query-Filter].RegionCode,
 [02-Query-Filter].NationalCode, [02-Query-Filter].Year, [02-Query-Filter].RawMonth
```

Comment: You might be able to in a report, but i'm not sure about a query because you want to create rows that have no data. Unless you actually have a row for every month, even if there are no sales. (?)

Comment: Hi, yes, I have already made it so that I get a row for each month. So this part works. However, the downside is that I get this for products with no sales at all as well. So I would like to filter out the years where there have been no sales at all in a region.

Comment: Might be easiest to start with a separate query that only gets products with sales. Than use that as the basis for step 2 (your query above), which shows every month.

Comment: Use a separate query as for the suggestion of wazz . Or add a subquery using WHERE NOT EXISTS to you query that retrieves all products where the sale of a product is "0" in a year for any particular product and region.

Answer (score 0):

You'd create a sub-query that selects all products, regions and all years (summing up as appropriate), and exclude combinations that are summing to 0. Call this X.

Then create another query that returns all products, regions and all year/month, keeping also the year and month fields (or at least the year field) separate. combinations. Call this Y.

Create another query Z that selects all records from Y which can be inner joined to X on product, region and year.

If I have understood the original problem, query Z will give you the data you seek.